Экспорт из документа Microsoft Word в таблицу Sql Server
Как можно выполнить экспорт данных из файла Microsoft Word(например один paragraph) в поле таблице Sql Server с помощью C# и microsoft.office.interop.word? Сложность заключается в том, что в параграфе может находится не только текст, но и рисунки (shapes, lines и т.д.). Я так понимаю в таблице Sql поле должно быть VarBinary. Как загрузить туда данные из Word? Помогите!

Можно скопировать абзац в другой файл ворда и этот файл в виде байт записать в БД.

В файле не один абзац. Нужно считывать циклом и заносить в таблицу.

Сколько абзацев, столько и файлов можно создать.
